# Protractor - is it possible to do multiple check on an element with a single 'expect' statement?

Tags: protractor

I wonder if it is possible to chain the checks on an element inside the same 'expect' statement.
For example, instead of this:

```
expect(loginPage.getLoginPageBackground().isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
expect(loginPage.getLoginPageBackground().isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

something like this:

`expect(loginPage.getLoginPageBackground().isPresent().isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`

This is just a random example. I know this won't work but I guess you get the concept. If there is any workaround, would like to hear that. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually exactly for your question you don't need to separately do isPresent and isDisplayed check, since isDisplayed is already does isPresent check inside:

`expect(loginPage.getLoginPageBackground().isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy('Optional error message here');`

FYI: isDisplayed() throws error in case element does not exist in DOM.

But in case you want to assert other conditions - you can use ExpectedConditions functions - `and(), or(), not()` to combine various checks together:

```
const EC = ExpectedConditions
const myElem = $('div')
await browser.wait(
      EC.and(
             EC.visibilityOf(myElem),
             EC.textToBePresentInElement(myElem, 'hello world!'),
      ),
      10000 // timeout
      `Optional error message`
)
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks like the thing I've been searching for. Just for clarification, what are the differences between using 'Expected Conditions' check and 'expect' assertion

Answer (score -1):

Answer is NO, you can't do that. Please give the complete context so that I can suggest work a round to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Well, my target is to avoid from making the same call multiple times like "loginPage.getLoginPageBackground()". I would like to do further checks once I get the element instead of making another call and doing another check

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to do that. You can do something like let *ele=loginPage.getLoginPageBackground()* and use **ele** multiple times but its still the same. Performance wise it doesn't make much of a difference if that's what you are thinking of. Also I don't think any problem using **loginPage.getLoginPageBackground()** multiple times.